# Raspberry Pi as JTAG programmer?

Tags: raspberry-pi, jtag

Other than obviously non-trivial problem of writing the software, is there any practical reason why the GPIO port of a Raspberry Pi couldn't be used as a JTAG programmer? I ask because I'm doing some hobby work with interfacing a CPLD to my  Raspberry Pi and it would be convenient to be able to program it directly rather than using a separate JTAG device and computer.

Are there any issues with voltages, timing etc...?

Comment: Bit banging jtag from user mode under linux is likely to be a tad slow, but it is do-able.  You could consider taking the functionality of an external jtag adapter and sticking it in a kernel module for higher efficiency.  Unfortunately the raspberry pi's gpio details are not as thoroughly documented in public literature as those of most processors used for this kind of task, but you can likely find enough information to make it basically work.

Comment: Thanks, for the CPLDs I'm interested in slow is acceptable as the files are very small but that's a good idea.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the CPLD mention, which should make it more reasonable than large FPGAs or their config flashes.  You might look for PC parallel port examples as a starting point.  Or get the JAM or SVF player source or whatever the vendor offers and build that with a modified output stage.

Answer (score 8):

[OpenOCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_Cortex-M_development_tools#Debugging_tools) has a generic sysfsgpio driver and have had a specific Raspberry Pi BCM2835 driver for quite some time, and AFAICT the speed is fine (e.g. STM32F1 flashing is limited by the speed of its flash) - about 4 MHz is easily obtainable and for many usecases no external circuity is needed. There's also support for [SWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG#Serial_Wire_Debug), but it's not yet upstream.

You should clone the current Git HEAD and compile it natively with `--enable-bcm2835gpio`, and then use config from `interface/raspberrypi-native.cfg`.

Please refer to the official README and [Texinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) manual for the specifics.

Regarding the hardware part of the question: If the target voltage is equal or very close to 3.3 V you can connect the Raspberry Pi's pins directly to the target interface, if not, you might (not always needed as many modern microcontrollers have "5 V-tolerant" pins, so they can be connected to sources with voltages higher than their V<sub>cc</sub> without any damage, but check the documentation first!) need to add an appropriate voltage-translation buffer.

To provide better impedance-matching, it's recommended to have 47-100 ohms series resistors on every signal line, close to the Raspberry Pi connector. For more details, please see Michael Schwingen's detailed explanation, *[Re: High output drive capability in Raspberry Pi](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.debugging.openocd.devel/23792)*.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would consider is that even if bit-banging I/O is slow, you might be able to (slowly) program a CPLD which could then be used to perform other operations much more quickly.  For example, if you had ten output pins D0-D9 which were all on the same I/O port, along with an input pin, you could use D9 as a "trigger" input, where a change of state (rising or falling) would, after a short delay (long enough for all other pins to settle), trigger the CPLD to do something.  D8 could select whether the "something" was supposed to be "output the data on D0-D7" or something else.  D4-D7 could then select one of 16 operations to perform (enable/disable a mode where the outputs simply follow the states of D0-D2, configure a boundary-scan-acceleration mode where each bit supplied by the ARM will clock out a group of three bits, which may be fixed high, fixed low, or follow the ARM state, etc.)  I'm not sure what sort of timing you would normally expect to get from the Raspberry Pi's I/O, but even a relatively small CPLD might be able to accelerate things greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small interface circuit which reads data that comes over the GPIO pins and resend it with the proper voltage levels, timing, etc. The voltage might have to be shifted if the Raspberry Pi is running at a voltage lower/higher than the CPLD, but I don't have any idea about the timing.

Comment: Well that's really what I'm asking. As I'm mostly a programmer doing a bit of electronics for a hobby I figure I could probably write the necessary code to do this, but I just wanted to know if it was practical at all before wasting my time on it. If it needs an aditional adapter then I might as well just use my existing programmer.

Comment: Well, maybe if both of them run at the same voltage levels it may be possible.

Comment: Ok thanks, looks like you can run the jtag at a range of voltages on the cpld including 3.3v although I think it may be using 1.8v on the board I have